# How do I connect a new project folder to an existing MAMP database?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, mamp

### Summary

I have an existing mySQL database on my MAMP server and I would like to connect a new site project to that database.

#### General Info

- I have another site root folder in `htdocs` using that database that is working
- **Error**: MySQL Error #2002 – The server is not responding
- The site root folder is in the `htdocs` folder
- The details with the error said my credentials are correct.
- Verified that all of the above information is the same as the database
- **wp_options** - siteurl and home are set to http://localhost:8888/my-site-folder

If my wp-config settings match the database values what else should I be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone finds this:

The only solution I discovered was to simply start a new wordpress installation with a new database. I was unable to find a way to connect to a different database.